# intellij control slash not working in jsp

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to intellij. I am able to comment out the code in java classes by using ctrl+/ . But if I try the same in jsp or tag file ,the code is not getting commented.

Thanks,In advance.

Comment: Do you use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate?

Comment: community edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition has no JSP language support (only the basic syntax highlighting).

Commenting the code requires the proper support from the language plug-in which is [available only](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.